# Strange behavior using Mage_Catalog_Model_Category

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I'm trying to get a certain category to display on one of my pages and I some strange results. I'm using the following code to load the category with the ID of 5

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load(5);
```

However, this returns NO results, even though there are products in the category. I've changed the `ID` to 2 (which is the default category) and this returns 2 products, even though there is no products in that category!

This is how I'm loading the code, I created a Static Block called "Get By Category", enabled it and filled it with the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/product/by_category.phtml"}}
```

Then, I created a new page and added that Static Block to it.

Has anyone else experienced this before? Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: The category should be instantiated using the model factory method `Mage::getModel('catalog/category)`. The method call `$category->load(5)` always returns the loaded model, so I believe your question might be rephrased a little. Also, there is no such thing like a default category. I assume you mean the root category? What is the value of the `is_anchor` setting for the root category? Are the products visible if you search for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically, to load the product list of a category you have to do it as the following:

```
$catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(/* your category ID*/);
$collection = $catalog->getProductCollection();
Zend_Debug::dump($collection->getItems());
```

This code won't work like that in a static block. You will have to create a class of type Mage_Core_Block_Template (or similar) and prepare the collection with a predefined category ID then in your Static Block, you can use the following code {{block type="catalog/mynewblock" template="catalog/product/mynewblock.phtml" category_id='my_category_ID_value'}}

When the block will be instantiated by the CMS module and thanks to filter Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter, the block will have the value of category_id. In the Block you will have to do the following:

```
protected function _beforeHtml(){ // or in the protected function _toHtml() depending of what you want to do and how you want to do it.
    $categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();
    $catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $collection = $catalog->getProductCollection();
    $products = $collection->getItems();
    $this->setProducts($products); // in your template file you can, then, do $this->getproducts(); etc...
    ...
}
```

You can find other information in the answer I wrote here [How to display multiple categories with a Magento block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8256203/469995)